Почему не получается установить Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop?
Скачивал разные версии Ubuntu (22.04. lts, 22.10):





Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Наверно, более внятные логи где-то выше по прокрутке (если прокрутка там вообще есть)

Возможно вы накатываете 32-бит убунту на 64-бит систему. Или наоборот. Проверьте что архитектура дистрибутива соответствует архитектуре процессора. Это касается не только разрядности.

архитектура соответствует

Live дистрибутив с этой архитектурой вы загрузить можете?

@StanislavVolodarskiy а на скриншотах что?)

@andreymal, я не знаю что там. Первые выглядят как логи загрузки, последний - терминал Убунты, которые что-то там не компилирует. Но я не уверен на 100%.

Сколько оперативы дал виртуалке?
